# Problems with new Date() in JS

Tags: javascript, html, date, dom

I have a web-page with `<input type="date">` where user chooses date. I get this date with DOM API method and create a Date object:

`article.createdAt = new Date(form.elements['date'].value);`

As a result my date is correct, but the time is always the same, 00:00. I want i to be the time when user chooses the date or at least that he'll be able to set time manually.

Need some advice with that. Thank you for help.

Comment: Create another Date instance with no parameters and copy the hours and minutes.

Comment: @Nikita could you show me your HTML & JS code

Comment: What is the actual value being returned by the date control? It should be something like "2017-04-10".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `datetime-local` instead of `date`

**Demo**

```html
<p>Click the button to create a Local Datetime field.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "datetime-local");
    x.setAttribute("default-value", "2015-01-02T11:42:13.510");
    x.setAttribute("value", "2015-01-02T11:42:13.510");
    document.body.appendChild(x);
    alert(x.value);
    alert(new Date(x.value));
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's working. Maybe you can tell me what should I do to make new Date without considering with my timezone?
For example, I input 04:33 AM and new Date is created with the time 07:33 AM (my timezone is UTC +3).

Comment: You don't have to use `.setAttribute()` here. You can directly set the "type", "defaultValue", and "value" properties of the DOM element.

Comment: @NikitaSavanovich timezone is because of `T` in the middle. You can remove that `T` before passing the input to a `Date` constructor

Comment: Code-only answers aren't that helpful. You should explain why or how your code fixes the OP's issue. You're relying on "2015-01-02T11:42:13.510" being correctly parsed by the built-in parser, which is not a good idea.

Comment: @RobG basically the answer is to replace `type="date"` to `type="datetime-local"`, so that time values are coming with the date object itself. I agree that passing date is not exactly the right thing, but I am assuming that OP will parse the date entered by user rather than setting his own.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 ways of initiating a date:

1. new Date()
2. new Date(milliseconds)
3. new Date(dateString)
4. new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)

You can follow of them,May be your problem will be solved.

find out the result as a string of this code `form.elements['date'].value`
then you follow the third number.

Comment: I think you meant instantiating instead of initiating

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're retrieving the date input correctly, check your console to see if it gives you any errors, and try getting your date like this

```
article.createdAt = new Date(form.querySelector("input[type='date']").value);
```

Comment: If the control is in a form, then to be successful it must have a name, so `form.controlName.value` is much more robust and a lot less to type. ;-) Also, this doesn't address the issue of getting the time associated with the date.